# Maple and Latex graphics geometry

Tags: geometry, maple2e

hello to all the community, I have a query, I am writing a geometry book at school level, I have been using latex and it is going well for me, the only complication I have is regarding the graphics, I want to know if there is the possibility that the graphics can be done in Maple and add them to Latex, or in the case that it is not possible in Maple, what software to use, I thank you very much.

Comment: you can presumably output the graphics from maple in a from that pdflatex can include such as pdf

Comment: Also, keep in mind Geogebra. It could be useful for some mathematical graphics

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). You may also want to consider `tikz` for drawing and `pfgplots` for gaphing functions.

Comment: or the package euclideangeometry: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/euclideangeometry